# Best way to asynchronously load external js files via Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am building a website that uses some external js files. I load the files via the code below, but I am not sure how to proceed if one or more of the files fails downloading. Should I just keep requesting them until all of them download? Is it better to do a separate onload event for each file? How would I know which file has failed loading and needs to be requested again?

```
var filesToLoad = ["https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"];

var loader = new ScriptLoader();
filesToLoad.forEach(function(file) {
    loader.add(file);
});

loader.loaded(function(failedCallbackF) {
    console.log("Error.");
    //Try getting the files again??
});

function ScriptLoader() {
    var promises = [];

    this.add = function(url) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;

            script.addEventListener('load', function() {
                resolve(script);
            }, false);

            script.addEventListener('error', function() {
                reject(script);
                console.log('was rej');
            }, false);

            document.body.appendChild(script);
        });

        promises.push(promise);
    };

    this.loaded = function(callbackOnFailed) {
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(result1) {
            console.log('Script loaded from:', result1);
        }, callbackOnFailed);
    };
}
```

Comment: Are those scripts required for your application to work? If that's the case, what other option do you have?

Comment: In my opinion you have to create new instance for each file. The benifite of this will be that if any file will fail to load then in its error function you can reload it only.

Comment: @Joanquin O Should I restructure my code to have it so every time `reject(script)` is hit, a new promise is made and it goes in a loop like that until all promises are resolved?

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is an official API for it called ["dynamic import"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), I recommend that you use it or shim it (with something like SystemJS or with a tool that supports it like webpack).

```
import("yourScriptFile.js").then(function(){
   // script loaded.
});
```

If you want to load multiple files you can also use it:

```
Promise.all(["url1", "url2"].map(System.import)).then(function(){
    // loaded all here
});
```

Comment: For loading multiple files, how would I know which file has failed loading and needs to be requested again?

Comment: @Autumn why would a script file fail loading? This is not something that you do in regular script tags anyway. If you _really_ want to you can use `.catch` on the returned promises and retry there.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the "*dynamic loader API*"? Thanks. I would like to know if this API supports aborting scripts as well (custom timeout)

Comment: @vsync Hey Yair, `SystemJS` is dead and so is the `System.import` spec - the new way forward is dynamic JavaScript import which is specified here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import - I will update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

May be this will help you.

```
var filesToLoad = ["https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"];   

filesToLoad.forEach(function(file) {
    var loader = new ScriptLoader();
    loader.add(file)
    loader.loaded(function(failedCallbackF) {
        console.log("Error.");
        //reload this file
    });

});

function ScriptLoader() {
    var promises = [];

    this.add = function(url) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;

            script.addEventListener('load', function() {
                resolve(script);
            }, false);

            script.addEventListener('error', function() {
                reject(script);
                console.log('was rej');
            }, false);

            document.body.appendChild(script);
        });

        promises.push(promise);
    };

    this.loaded = function(callbackOnFailed) {
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(result1) {
            console.log('Script loaded from:', result1);
        }, callbackOnFailed);
    };
}
```